# How can I shoot a timelapse with a Canon Powershot camera?

Tags: canon, timelapse, powershot

I have a Canon Powershot ELPH 190 IS.

Does anyone know if there is an Android application to record a timelapse on the camera?

If not, is there a compatible intervalometer?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://global.canon/cca/) your camera is compatible with Canon Camera Connect (Android/iOS) application. And it support:

- Wi-Fi connection with the camera for image transfer and remote live
  view shooting.
- Adding location information to camera images
- NFC touch operation with enabled cameras

Unfortunately I am not sure if application can support timelapse. Also you should consider camera battery life which is 190 photos (CIPA)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a timelapse is possible with that camera, given that it's sort of a barebones point and shoot without many external interfaces. Getting a physical intervalometer would require having something that can repeatedly press the shutter button on the camera.

Most add-on intervalometers require a shutter release port on the camera, which the IXUS/ELPH cameras do not have.  And they do not have intervalometer functions in their menus.  While the 190 IS does have wi-fi capability that would let you [connect to the Canon Camera Connect app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKXu3IiTmU0), whose remote shooting functions can take the place of most shutter remotes, the app does not include an intervalometer function.

Typically in this situation, with most Canon Powershot cameras, [the CHDK (Canon Hack Development Kit)](https://chdk.fandom.com/wiki/CHDK) would probably be the answer, but it looks like there is no build for the IXUS 180/ELPH 190 IS. And since this is a firmware hack, using a build for a different model/firmware version could brick your camera.

You may want to consider getting a different point and shoot camera, say, a Panasonic ZS or a higher-end Powershot, that has a time lapse function in its menus, if this is really important to you.